# How to upload, download files in server side web serivce

Tags: web-services, swing, rest, file-upload, download

How do I upload files in a REST web service? The Java Swing application will call REST web service to use the upload method.

I used apache.commons.fileupload but it is for web-based applications.

How do I download files? I used FileReader and PrintWriter. it is ok for other files, but I have a problem with pictures and zip files. What lib do I need to use to download binary files, pictures, zip, HTML, etc.?

Comment: See the [Basic I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) lesson of the Java Tutorial for most answers on how to download a resource from a server.

Comment: hi andrew, i am not a little understand what you mean "how to do this form command line and 98% of the way how to do using Swing"? It's impossible to implement? Coz I am doing cloud storage and my supervisor ask me to do web service for swing

Comment: "It's impossible to implement?"  No, I did not mean that at all!  I just meant that if it worked from the command line, it would then be easy to add the 'with Swing' functionality.  A `JButton` with an `ActionListener` attached, creating a `JFileChooser`, and if the user selects a `File` for upload, creating a `SwingWorker` that updates a `JProgressBar` - and it is done. ...OK, maybe the job is **80%** done. And BTW - 99% of statistics are made up on the spur of the moment.  ;)  But either way - try to separate the file upload/download from the Swing aspect.  They are largely different qns.

Comment: BTW, do you know which lib file need to used to upload?

Comment: I am not experienced with server side development, so cannot comment on that aspect.  For the client side part of a file upload, it is also largely covered in the Basic I/O lesson.  Thinking about it, I recommend you edit your question to remove the mention of Swing and just reduce it to 'server side file upload'.  Ask other more specific questions on separate threads.

Comment: When you do get it working on its own and integrate the solution into your Swing GUI, make sure you do these long running operations outside the gui thread. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253028/15789

For anyone who stumbles upon this page - the above may help. It is an example REST service that receives bytes of a file and sends zipped bytes in response. Using JAX-RS Client to send request and receive response.