# Uploading a zip file using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am getting an HTTP POST request via which passes a .zip file. I am using Jersey to implement this.

I need to download the zip file and unzip the file.
I know how to unzip the file, but not sure how to go about downloading the file.

Please help me out as i am a beginner in this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search SO?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716357/jersey-client-to-download-and-save-file

Comment: I need to save the incoming zip file to my hard drive. This is for downloading the file to the client side

Answer (score 0):

After going through many many questions on stackoverflow and online sites, 
I got to know a very foolish mistake made by me.

I did not include the jersey-multipart.jar file.

Thanks for the help anyways.