# File Upload using Rest API in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file-upload, jersey

I am new to REST API. I want to upload user selected file to the user provided path(remote or local path) using REST API. My html file is having 1 text box and 1 file chooser. User will enter FilePath (local or remote machine folder location) in the text box.
Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Here is my code:

**FileUpload.html:**:

```
<body>
    <form action="rest/file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
        </p>
        <p>Target Upload Path : <input type="text" name="path" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
   </form>
</body>
```

**UploadFileService.java**

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
            @FormParam("path") String path) {

        /*String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/"                                                                 + fileDetail.getFileName();*/

        /*String uploadedFileLocation = //10.217.14.88/Installables/uploaded/"                                                                  + fileDetail.getFileName();*/
        String uploadedFileLocation = path
                + fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<display-name>JAXRSFileUploadJerseyExample</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Exception:**

```
HTTP Status 500 - com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters
type Exception report
message com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception obtaining parameters
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:54)
        com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:125)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.parameter.FormParamInjectableProvider$FormParamInjectable.getValue(FormParamInjectableProvider.java:81)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
        com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:125)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have updated signature of method in below class and its working fine.
Instead of `@FormParam`, used `@FormDataParam("path")` String path and it solved my issue.
Below is the updated code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
        @FormDataParam("path") String path) {


    // Path format //10.217.14.97/Installables/uploaded/
    System.out.println("path::"+path);
    String uploadedFileLocation = path
            + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to new location
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

   }
```

Comment: will the java code accept any type of file and save it in the defined location??
I want to save file-types like .pdf, .doc, .jpg

Comment: if above code has problems with jars use this maven import: <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution

@Consumes annotation and set it to application octet stream. Use PUT http method. Then in the client, read bytes from file and upload.

My sample code for a REST service to zip a file is here - 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32253028/15789

Hope this helps.