# create a image file using java.io.reader java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, reader

this is my java rest api code

```
@POST
@Path("{imageTitle}/uploadPic")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response uploadPic(Reader PicFile,
        @PathParam("imageTitle") String imageTitle) {

    String uploadPath = "/home/dev/";

    //What is next..????

}
```

how to create a file using reader input?

Comment: In Java, `Reader` and its subclasses are for reading text files. Since Images are stored in binary files, you really should be using an `InputStream`

Comment: possible duplicate of [File Upload using Rest API in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890675/file-upload-using-rest-api-in-java)

Comment: see also http://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-upload-example

Comment: Make use of ImageIO to create a image in stream

Comment: also, you probably want to use a POST request and not GET, but maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: anyone can give me a sample code to write reader object to a file