# Can I have file and request body in an API

Tags: java, api, multipartform-data, multipart

I have one condition where I need a multipart file as parameter and another request body in which some details related to file will be there, so is it possible for me to do that ?

```
@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestBody CandidteEmailDTO dto
```

Comment: are fixed this issue Vipul? I have same issue can you please give me suggition if you fixed.Thanks in advance

Comment: No Sairam, it wasn't resolved, but I changed the criteria, now I am taking file in candidateEmailDTO only, and I am taking that in byte array format, SO i think that can help you also

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to do. You should just ensure that you don't forget to declare enctype = "multipart/form-data", in your form tag.

Comment: But how I will pass a request here? because when I see in postman I can either send form data in which we can have file or we can send 'raw' object in the form of json, we can't send both of them together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902176/7755988). I think that you need to change the `@RequestParam` to `@FormDataParam`