# Zipping and password protect file using camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have been trying to zip multiple csv file in my route. I have been successfully able to do that.

I am using spring to do the same.

Now the new requirement is to **password protect them**. Following is the aggregation strategy I have used. How to achieve this?

```
<route autoStartup="false" routePolicyRef="routeTwoTimer" startupOrder="2" id="zippingFileRoute">
    <from uri="{{to.file.processed1}}"/>
    <choice id="csvZipFile">
        <when>
            <simple>$simple{header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*(csv|CSV)$'</simple>
            <aggregate strategyRef="zipAggregationStrategy" completionFromBatchConsumer="true" eagerCheckCompletion="true">
                <correlationExpression>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </correlationExpression>
                <to uri="{{to.file.processed2}}"/>
            </aggregate>
        </when>
    </choice>
</route>
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Are you saying you don't know what to do? Have you tried something and it isn't working?

Comment: Yes Ray I do not know how can it be done.

Comment: You're right, the [actual documentation](http://camel.apache.org/zip-file-dataformat.html) does not say anything about any zip options (like passwords). I guess it is not supported as-is. One option would be to crypt all files and then compress (in the zip), or compress and crypt the zip file after.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10587717/628006) says there's no password encryption in Java OOB. However there are few libraries that can be integrated to your project. I would personally create a specific Camel Processor to use the library to create the Zip file.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments, Java API is a bit limited in encrypting ZIP files. Apache Camel `ZipAggregationStrategy` is using `ZipOutputStream`, so there is this limitation too. You can implement custom `Aggregator` using any other library, which allows encryption of Zip files. For example [Zip4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2)

**Add Maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Implement custom Aggregator**

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
//next few imports. I have added this only to take correct ZipFile class, not the JDK one 

public class PasswordZipAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {

public static final String ZIP_PASSWORD_HEADER = "PasswordZipAggregationStrategy.ZipPassword";

@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange){
    try {
        if (newExchange == null) {
            return oldExchange;
        }
        return aggregateUnchecked(oldExchange,newExchange);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private Exchange aggregateUnchecked(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) throws Exception{
    ZipFile zipFile;
    String password;
    if (oldExchange == null) { // first
        password = newExchange.getIn().getHeader(ZIP_PASSWORD_HEADER, String.class);
        zipFile = new ZipFile(newExchange.getExchangeId()+".zip");
        File toDelete = new File(zipFile.getFile().getPath());
        newExchange.addOnCompletion(new Synchronization() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Exchange exchange) {
                toDelete.delete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exchange exchange) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        password = newExchange.getIn().getHeader(ZIP_PASSWORD_HEADER, String.class);
        zipFile = new ZipFile(oldExchange.getIn().getBody(File.class));
    }

    if (password==null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Null password given");
    }

    ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
    zipParameters.setPassword(password);
    zipParameters.setEncryptFiles(true);
    zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_FAST);
    zipParameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_STANDARD);
    zipFile.addFile(newExchange.getIn().getBody(File.class), zipParameters);
    GenericFile genericFile = FileConsumer.asGenericFile(zipFile.getFile().getParent(), zipFile.getFile(), Charset.defaultCharset().toString(), false);
    genericFile.bindToExchange(newExchange);

    newExchange.getIn().setBody(zipFile.getFile());
    newExchange.getIn().setHeader(ZIP_PASSWORD_HEADER, password);
    return newExchange;
}
}
```

**Use it**

```
from("file://in")
    .to("log:in")
    .setHeader(PasswordZipAggregationStrategy.ZIP_PASSWORD_HEADER, constant("testPassword"))
    .aggregate().constant(true).completionFromBatchConsumer()
        .aggregationStrategy(new PasswordZipAggregationStrategy())
.to("log:out")
.to("file://out");
```