# how to give the password protection to Zip folder in java?

Tags: java, encryption, passwords, zip, password-protection

I need to set password protection for Zip folder via java, not for zip folder files. Without password i should not be able to open the Zip folder.

This is the code i found from google.

```
 public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os)        
 throws Throwable {encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);                             
}
```

Comment: Check this link http://j2ee.ulitzer.com/node/1258827/mobile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32253028/15789 - My sample code on another thread may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done using winzipaes1.0.1.jar...

Sample Code...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import de.idyl.winzipaes.AesZipFileEncrypter;
import de.idyl.winzipaes.impl.AESEncrypterBC;

public class Practice1Main {

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{


    File aNewZipFile = new File("src.zip");
    File existingUnzippedFile = new File("src.txt");

    AESEncrypterBC encrypter = new AESEncrypterBC();
    encrypter.init("password", 0);  // The 0 is keySize, it is ignored for AESEncrypterBC

    AesZipFileEncrypter zipEncrypter = new AesZipFileEncrypter(aNewZipFile, encrypter);

    zipEncrypter.add(existingUnzippedFile, "src.txt", "password");
    zipEncrypter.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: friend,@ CoderNeji i need protection for zip folder only, no need of files in the zip folder

Comment: This will create a password protected zip file src.zip and on extraction it will give you src.txt... There is no password on txt file

Answer (score 2):

The only free library I know of that does this is *winzipaes*. It has an Apache licence.

Google Code project page => https://code.google.com/p/winzipaes/

Maven Repo Link => http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.idyl/winzipaes

Comment: but that jar cannot help me.. suggest any working code links @kkaosninja