# How to unzip the "Password Protected xlsx file" using java

Tags: java, xml, excel, xlsx

I am using java.util.zip package to unzip the xlsx files and using Stax parser for reading the data. Is it possible to unzip the password protected xlsx file using the `java.util.zip` package. When I try this I am not able to get the sheet.xml files , I can able to see only the encrypted folders.

Comment: Why you do not use apache poi for reading xslx files?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java API does not support password protected zip files.

Same question:

see this:
[Password protected zip file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587561/password-protected-zip-file-in-java)

then this:
http://java.sys-con.com/node/1258827