# Getting "negative time" exception when unpacking zip file with zip4j

Tags: java, zip, zip4j

I'm using [`zip4j`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.3.2) to extract `zip` files. For many users this works fine but a `Windows 8` user is getting the following exception:

```
net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
    at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.initExtractFile(Unzip.java:163)
    at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.initExtractAll(Unzip.java:83)
    at net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip.extractAll(Unzip.java:73)
    at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.extractAll(ZipFile.java:488)
    at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.extractAll(ZipFile.java:451)
    ...
```

Negative time seems to be caused by a [file on the file system having a negative time and/or by a JVM bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-270). Does anyone know how to fix this problem since this is quite odd and not related to my usage of the `API` I assume.

`zip4j` hasn't been maintained since `2013` so I wouldn't be surprised if it has some bugs but there just isn't another more capable `zip` library without boilerplate besides the `JDK` one. However, I need password protected zip file support and [that isn't supported by the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10587717/3764804).

Installing `JDK 11` and using it to run the application does not fix the problem but it was worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found `7-Zip-JBinding`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.sevenzipjbinding</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevenzipjbinding-all-platforms</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

The following code can be used to extract a password protected zip file:

```
public static void unzipUsing7Zip(String zipFilePath,
                                   String destinationDirectory,
                                   String password) throws IOException
{
    try (val randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(zipFilePath, "r");
         val randomAccessFileInStream = new RandomAccessFileInStream(randomAccessFile);
         val inArchive = openInArchive(null, randomAccessFileInStream))
    {
        val simpleInArchive = inArchive.getSimpleInterface();
        val archiveItems = simpleInArchive.getArchiveItems();

        for (val archiveItem : archiveItems)
        {
            if (!archiveItem.isFolder())
            {
                val archiveItemPath = archiveItem.getPath();
                val targetFilePath = destinationDirectory + separator + archiveItemPath;

                try (val fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFilePath))
                {
                    archiveItem.extractSlow(data ->
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (archiveItemPath.indexOf(separator) > 0)
                            {
                                // Create parent folder(s)
                                val lastSeparatorIndex = archiveItemPath.lastIndexOf(separator);
                                val path = destinationDirectory + separator + archiveItemPath.substring(0, lastSeparatorIndex);
                                createDirectories(Paths.get(path));
                            }

                            fileOutputStream.write(data);
                        } catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            exception.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return data.length;
                    }, password);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on [here](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/extraction_snippets.html) but cleaned up and real file extraction code via `FileOutputStream` added.

Additional note: `val` comes from `lombok` of course.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is the **current time** and the **latest file modification time**. The format does not match. You can check with this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
System.out.println(dtf.format(now));  

File file = new File("folder/source.zip");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(file.lastModified()));
```

Then setting your format in your **Region Setting** >> **Regional Format** >> **English (United States)**