# Set Password to a File to be Sent as an Email Attachment in SAP CPI

Tags: javascript, email, groovy, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cpi

Looking for a groovy script to create a password protected CSV file to send as an attachment through the mail adapter in SAP CPI. As in, when the recipient tries to access the file, he has to type in a password for it to happen. There's no CPI shape to directly execute this so I was looking into writing a script for the same.

Comment: What kind of file ? How is it password protected ? What have you tried ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Csv does not support password protection because it's  plait text file. You could use zip for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587561/password-protected-zip-file-in-java

Comment: Is there a javascript code or groovy script that i can refer for this? To create a zip file and then add a password to it

Comment: there's a standard element in CPI for creating a zip